# Straight polygon skeletons for random simple polygons

Tags: python, polygon

I want to generate straight polygon skeletons for randomly generated simple polygons in python.

I looked online for libraries for skeleton generation but they all seem to be outdated or not reliable.

Is there a library implementing the skeleton generation in python and how do I use it.